# When do I need use vendor prefixes?

Tags: css, cross-browser

When should I use `-webkit`, `-moz`, `-o` etc prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS property with prefix means that this is early browser implementation. After several browsers implement any css feature with prefix(rely on not recommended `W3C` spec) `W3C` fix any differences or mistakes in specification which where finding in implementation process and CSS feature become a W3C recommendation.

For example, prefixed `linear-gradient` syntax with prefix:

```
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3DC8FF 0%, #008CC3 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3DC8FF 0%, #008CC3 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3DC8FF), color-stop(100%, #008CC3));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3DC8FF 0%, #008CC3 100%);
```

And with out:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3DC8FF 0%, #008CC3 100%);
```

As you can see first argument changed: if you want gradient from top to bottom you need `top` value for prefixed css values and `to bottom` for `W3C` linear gradient recommendation.

So you need prefixes for older browser versions where there is unprefixed values or for that css properties that don't has `W3C recommended specification` and implemented rely on `W3C draft`.

As front-end developer you must support many browsers modern and older your css contains properties with prefixed for `Opera`(-o), `Firefox`(-moz) and `Chrome`, `Safari`(-webkit)

Also there are mobile browsers. Now you need use `-webkit` prefix for mobile, because `Mobile Safari`, for example, use only prefixed css properties. `Opera Classic`(Opera Mobile before 14 version) mobile browser is not updated and will always has -o prefixed css properties.